# Inputenc error with some minus signs on a table

Tags: tables, input-encodings

First of all, I'm new to writing in latex. So this might be a dumb question.

I'm trying to do the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,brazilian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
Nilvariedade            & tipo 3                 & tipo 2                   & tipo 1                           & tipo 0      \\
(0,0,12,13,14,15)       & Não admite             & Não admite               & (1+i2)exp i(36-45)               & 16+34-25    \\
(0,0,12,13,14,34+52)    & Não admite             & Não admite               & (1+i2)exp i(-45+36 +i(36+45))    & Não admite  \\
(0,0,12,13,14,23+15)    & Não admite             & Não admite               & (1+2i)exp i(36-45)               & 16+24+34-25 \\
(0,0,12,13,23,14)       & Não admite             & Não admite               & Não admite                       & 15+24+34-26 \\
(0,0,12,13,23,14−25)    & Não admite             & Não admite               & Não admite                       & 15+24−35+16 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile, Latex spits out "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:− not set up for use with LaTeX.", but only for the two minus signs on the 5th row of the table. There are minus signs on the other rows too, but latex sees no problem with them. When I remove the 5th row, everything run smoothly.

Actually, my table is much bigger than that (35 rows) and all the rows after the 5th that contains a minus have the same problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no minus sign in the fifth row between 14 and 25 in `(0,0,12,13,23,14−25)`. More precisely, as Manuel pointed out, this is not the hyphen dash that usually means a minus sign for most of math-related programs. This is in fact another dash, which is slightly bigger. There is also one more in the same line, between 24 and 35 in `15+24−35+16`. Replace them by the usual hyphen dash:  `(0,0,12,13,23,14-25)` and `15+24-35+16` and your example will run without problem.

Comment: ”real minus signs” seems not too accurate to me.

Comment: I mean, “real” brings me the idea of unicode minus signs (which I think exist),but what he wants are usual hyphen-dash (the one the computer inputs by default) which in math mode are treated as minus signs. It's a foreign language to me too, I was just pointing it out.

Comment: @Manuel You're right of course. I could have been more accurate indeed. And what I called "dash sign" is actually called "en-dash", if I remember correctly. Still, since in most of math-related programs the hyphen-dash is treated as minus sign (not only in TeX, but also in Matlab, Maxima, etc.), this does not seem too confusing to me.